# WPF load data from EF async

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have wpf application with EF6. I use:

```
context.Set<T>().Local;
```

as item source for listview. I want to ask, where I should call load data?

```
private async void MainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await context.Set<T>().LoadAsync();
    Items = context.Set<T>().Local; //Items is observable collection. Listbox is Bind for this
}
```

I try it in Window Loaded event, but that hangs application on start. What is the best solution? 
If I swap this two line or not call with await, then I get exception becouse I could not add to collection from another thread.

Comment: Try raising `PropertyChanged` event for `Items` property after setting it.

Comment: `but that hangs application on start` Why you think that the application hangs? What happens?

Comment: @sthotakura It works correctly, but load take a while and application start slow because this.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Application start, about 4-10s, depends on internet. By profiling tool 78% of start is line await context.Set<T>().LoadAsync();

Comment: What you mean by `application start`? Does the `MainWindow` appears after 4-10s? Or you see the loaded data in the `ItemsControl` from 4-10s?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan MainWindow appears after 4-10s

Comment: @Peter: Use a profiler to see where the delay is. It's probably not `await context.Set<T>().LoadAsync()`.

Comment: @StephenCleary this line takes 85.5%.

Comment: @Peter: Is that 85.5% of the `MainWindowLoaded` method, or 85.5% of the time to show the window?

Comment: @StephenCleary  the time to show the window

Comment: Window must be visible before Loaded event rises.

Comment: @Peter: I can see nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.